# How to memoize the repeated subtrees of a game tree (a potentially infinite rose tree)?

Tags: haskell, memoization, state-monad, multiway-tree, negamax

I am attempting to implement the [Negamax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax) algorithm in Haskell.

For this, I am representing the future possibilities a game might take in a rose tree (`Data.Tree.Forest (depth, move, position)`). However, often there are positions that can be reached with two different sequences of moves. It is a waste (and quickly becomes very slow) to re-evaluate (the subtrees of) repeated positions.

Here is what I tried so far:

- Implement a variant of [Tying the Knot](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tying_the_Knot) to share common sub-results. However, I have only been able to find explanations of tying the knot for (potentially infinite) lists, and nothing about re-using subtrees.
- Another approach I have considered was to build a tree inside the `State` monad, where the state to keep would be a `Map (depth, position) (Forest (depth, move, position))` to perform explicit memoization but I have so far not been able to set this up properly either.

I think that both approaches might have the problem that a game tree can only be built in a *corecursive* way: We do not build the tree up to the root from the leaves, but build a (potentially infinite) tree lazily from the root down.

---

EDIT: To give you an example of the code I am currently using (that is too slow):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module ZeroSumGame where

import qualified Control.Arrow
import Data.Tree

import Numeric.Natural (Natural)

(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
x |> f = f x
infixl 0 |>
{-# INLINE (|>) #-}

class Ord s => Game s where
  data Move s
  initial :: s -- | Beginning of the game
  applyMove :: Natural -> s -> Move s -> s -- | Moving from one game state to the next
  possibleMoves :: Natural -> s -> [Move s] -- | Lists moves the current player is able to do.
  isGameOver :: s -> Bool -- | True if the game has ended. TODO: Maybe write default implementation using `possibleMoves state == []`?
  scorePosition :: Natural -> Move s -> s -> Int -- | Turns a position in an integer, for the Negamax algorithm to decide which position is the best.

type Trimove state = (Natural, Move state, state) -- | Depth since start of game, move to next position, new position

gameforest :: Game s => Natural -> s -> Forest (Trimove s)
gameforest start_depth start_state = unfoldForest buildNode (nextpositions start_depth start_state)
  where
    buildNode (depth, move, current_state) =
      if
        isGameOver current_state
      then
        ((depth, move, current_state), [])
      else
        ((depth, move, current_state), nextpositions depth current_state)
    nextpositions depth current_state =
      current_state
      |> possibleMoves depth
      |> fmap (\move -> (succ depth, move, applyMove depth current_state move))

scoreTree :: Game s => Ord (Move s) => Natural -> Tree (Trimove s) -> (Move s, Int)
scoreTree depth node =
  case (depth, subForest node) of
    (0, _) ->
      node |> rootLabel |> uncurry3dropFirst scorePosition
    (_, []) ->
      node |> rootLabel |> uncurry3dropFirst scorePosition
    (_, children) ->
      children
      |> scoreForest (pred depth)
      |> map (Control.Arrow.second negate)
      |> maximum

uncurry3dropFirst :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> (a, b, c) -> (b, d)
uncurry3dropFirst fun (a, b, c) = (b, fun a b c)

scoreForest :: Game s => Ord (Move s) => Natural -> Forest (Trimove s) -> [(Move s, Int)]
scoreForest depth forest =
  forest
  |> fmap (scoreTree depth)
```

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module TicTacToe where

import qualified Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.State (State)
import qualified Data.Map
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Control.Arrow
import Data.Tree

import Data.Array (Array)
import qualified Data.Array
import qualified Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Foldable

import Numeric.Natural (Natural)


import ZeroSumGame

data CurrentPlayer = First | Second
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)


instance Enum CurrentPlayer where
  fromEnum First = 1
  fromEnum Second = -1
  toEnum 1 = First
  toEnum (-1) = Second
  toEnum _ = error "Improper player"

newtype TicTacToe = TicTacToe (Array (Int, Int) (Maybe CurrentPlayer))
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance Game TicTacToe where
  data Move TicTacToe = TicTacToeMove (Int, Int)
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Bounded)

  initial = TicTacToe initialTicTacToeBoard

  possibleMoves _depth = possibleTicTacToeMoves

  applyMove depth (TicTacToe board) (TicTacToeMove (x, y)) =
    TicTacToe newboard
    where
      newboard = board Data.Array.// [((x, y), Just player)]
      player = case depth `mod` 2 of
        0 -> First
        _ -> Second

  isGameOver state = Data.Maybe.isJust (findFilledLines state)

  scorePosition _ _ state =
          state
          |> findFilledLines
          |> fmap fromEnum
          |> Data.Maybe.fromMaybe 0
          |> (* (-10000))



findFilledLines :: TicTacToe -> Maybe CurrentPlayer
findFilledLines (TicTacToe board) =
  (rows ++ columns ++ diagonals)
  |> map winner
  |> Data.Foldable.asum
  where
    rows = vals rows_indexes
    columns = vals columns_indexes
    diagonals = vals diagonals_indexes
    rows_indexes = [[(i, j) | i <- [0..2]]| j <- [0..2]]
    columns_indexes = [[(i, j) | j <- [0..2]]| i <- [0..2]]
    diagonals_indexes = [[(i, i) ]| i <- [0..2]] ++ [[(i, 2 - i) ]| i <- [0..2]]
    vals = map (map (\index -> board Data.Array.! index))

winner :: Eq a => [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
winner [x,y,z] =
  if x == y && x == z then x else Nothing
winner _ = Nothing


initialTicTacToeBoard :: (Array (Int, Int) (Maybe CurrentPlayer))
initialTicTacToeBoard =
  Data.Array.array ((0, 0), (2, 2)) [((i, j), Nothing) | i <- [0..2], j <- [0..2]]

possibleTicTacToeMoves :: TicTacToe -> [Move TicTacToe]
possibleTicTacToeMoves (TicTacToe board) = foldr checkSquareForMove [] (Data.Array.assocs board)
    where
      checkSquareForMove (index, val) acc = case val of
        Nothing -> TicTacToeMove index : acc
        Just _ -> acc

printBoard :: TicTacToe -> String
printBoard (TicTacToe board) =
  unlines [unwords [showTile (board Data.Array.! (y, x)) | x <- [0..2]] |  y <- [0..2]]
  where
    showTile loc =
      case loc of
        Nothing -> " "
        Just Second -> "X"
        Just First -> "O"
```

(TypeFamilies is used to allow each `Game` implementation to have their own notion of a `Move`, and FlexibleContexts is then required to enforce `Move s` to implement `Ord`.

Comment: This is a really cool question! Too bad I can't help you out with it ...

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem reformulation

If I understand the question correctly, you have a function that returns the possible next moves in a game, and one to take that move:

```
start :: Position
moves :: Position -> [Move]
act :: Position -> Move -> Position
```

and how you want to build the infinite tree of states (please allow me to ignore the `Depth` field, for simplicity. If you consider the depth counter as part of the `Position` type, you see that no generality is lost here):

```
states :: Forest (Position, Move)
states = forest start

forest :: Position -> Forest (Position, Move)
forest p = [ Node (m, p') (states p') | m <- moves p, let p' = act p m ]
```

but you want to achieve that in a way that identical subtrees of `forest` are shared.

#### Towards Memoization

The general technique is here is that we want to memoize `forest`: This way, for identical `Positions`, we get shared subtrees. So the recipe is:

```
forest :: Position -> Forest (Position, Move)
forest = memo forest'

forest' :: Position -> Forest (Position, Move)
forest' p = [ Node (m, p') (states p') | m <- moves p, let p' = act p m ]
```

And we need a suitable memo-function:

```
memo :: (Position -> a) -> (Position -> a)
```

At this point, we need to know more about `Position` in order to know how to implement that using an equivalent of the “lazy list” trick… But you see that you do *not* need to memoize functions that involve Rose trees.

Comment: Interesting answer! The depth is mostly relevant to keep track of which player's turn it is, but you are right that no generality is lost. 

How is a function like the `memo` you mentioned able to perform memoization? Some behind-the-scenes `unsfafePerform` trickery?

Comment: @Qqwy, actually no hacks are necessary, it's quite beautiful. See the haskellwiki page about memoization. There are several libraries to help -- data-memocombinators and MemoTrie ... depending on your aesthetic

Comment: @Qqwy, what is the type of `Position`? Then we can look at that. Or look at the existing memo combinators, like @luqui suggests.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner In the case of e.g. Tic Tac Toe, Position would be typed as `newtype TicTacToe = TicTacToe (Array (Int, Int) (Maybe CurrentPlayer))
  deriving (Eq, Ord)`. As I am building it as a typeclass, however, `position` is one of the two types that differ between games. Maybe it is more helpful to share the interface of the typeclass. (Since the code is too long for a comment, see the edited question)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do this by normalizing board positions based on some "canonical" sequence of moves to reach that position. Then each child is assigned the value of traversing its individual normalized sequence through the tree. (no code because I'm on my phone and this is a big task.)

How well this works depends on the ease of calculating normalized move sequences in the game you're playing. But it's a way to introduce sharing by tying the knot, making use of a shared reference to the root of the game tree. Maybe it will serve as inspiration for other ideas that fit your specific case.

Comment: I intend to create the negamax algorithm as a typeclass that can be implemented for any zero sum games (like Chess, Checkers, TicTacToe, Connect-Four, Reversi, Shogi, Xiangi, etc). I have no idea if it is at all possible to define a 'canonical sequence' for each of these games' positions.

Comment: The method generally used by chess engines to hash chess board positions is called [Zobrist hashing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing). Perhaps something similar would be suitable for your game. You could define a typeclass that extends the negamax class to add a hash function for suitable games. You might look at the [astar package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/astar-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Graph-AStar.html)'s parameterized generic A* search for inspiration there.